# Implement an Interface method with different generic types for parameters and return

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface like this

```
public interface KeyGenerator {
    <T,V> T generateKey(V parameters);
}
```

and I want to implement this function, with these data types

```
public class SomeSpecificKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator

public List<String> generateKey(SomeParameterClass parameters){
    // do something
}
```

getting error, that the interface method must be implemented (which I am trying to, in the above snippet)

Comment: define the generic types T and V at the class level after that create an instance of Specifickeygenerator and call the generatekey method

Comment: As said in the comment above, you have to add the generic and concrete types to the classes: `public interface KeyGenerator<V, T>` and `public class SomeSpecificKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator<SomeParameterClass, String>`

Answer (score 0):

you can write this way and getting no error

```
public class SomeSpecificKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator{
    @Override
    public <T, V> T generateKey(V parameters) {
        return null;
    }
}
```